# Set difference of two character sets C++

Tags: c++, stl, set

#### Problem

I have two sorted sets:

```
set<char, greater<char> > alp1;
set<char, greater<char> > alp;
```

I need to find the set difference: **alp-alp1**:

#### Attempt 1

```
set_difference(alp.begin(), alp.end(), alp1.begin(), alp1.end(), inserter(diff1, diff1.end()));
```

But, only the first element of `alp1` is subtracted from `alp`.

#### Attempt 2

```
itr = set_difference(alp.begin(), alp.end(), alp1.begin(), alp1.end(), diff1.begin());
for(auto it=diff.begin(); it<itr; it++)
   cout<<*it;
```

#### Attempt 2 Error:

```
no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<char>’ and ‘std::set<char>::const_iterator’ {aka ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<char>’})
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass a `greater<char>()` comparator to `set_difference`, the same comparator you use for your sets (see [full API](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference)):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  set<char, greater<char>> alp = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
  set<char, greater<char>> alp1 = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
  set<char, greater<char>> diff;
  set_difference(alp.begin(), alp.end(), alp1.begin(), alp1.end(),
                 inserter(diff, diff.begin()), greater<char>());
  for (const char c : diff) {
    cout << c;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ed
```

Demo: http://cpp.sh/3be2u.